# In $pqr$ method, if $q+r=4$, show that $p^2-2q+3r\ge2p$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> Positive numbers $x$, $y$ and $z$ satisfy $xy+yz+zx+xyz=4$, show that
> \[x^2+y^2+z^2+3xyz\ge2(x+y+z).\]

I thought of $pqr$ method, let $\begin{cases}p=x+y+z,\\q=xy+yz+zx,\\r=xyz.\end{cases}$ so we have $q+r=4$, and needed to prove
\[p^2-2q+3r\ge2p.\]
Transform into $(p-1)^2-2q+3r\ge1$. Since $q$, $r$ have a condition, I wanted to get rid of $p$. Clearly $p>1$ (actually $p\ge3$), by $p^2\ge3q$, it suffices to prove
\[\left(\sqrt{3q}-1\right)^2-2q+3(4-q)\ge1.\]This resulted in $q+\sqrt{3q}\le6$, which is false because we can prove $q\ge3$. If we change $p$ into something else it will become only weaker so it cannot work. Perhaps we couldn't use $pqr$ method here.

Any method is okay, except for Lagrange Multipliers, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pqr method:

It suffices to prove that
$$p^2 - 2q + 3r - 2p + (4 - q - r) \ge 0$$
or
$$p^2 - 2p + 4 + 2r - 3q\ge 0.$$

Degree three Schur's inequality
yields $p^3 - 4pq + 9r \ge 0$
which results in
$q \le \frac{p^3 + 9r}{4p}$.

It suffices to prove that
$$p^2 - 2p + 4 + 2r - 3\cdot \frac{p^3 + 9r}{4p}\ge 0$$
or
$$p(p-4)^2 - (27-8p)r \ge 0. \tag{1}$$

If $27 - 8p \le 0$, clearly (1) is true.

If $27 - 8p > 0$, using $p^3 \ge 27r$,
we have
$$p(p-4)^2 - (27-8p)r
\ge p(p-4)^2 - (27-8p)\cdot \frac{p^3}{27} = \frac{8}{27}p(p+6)(p-3)^2 \ge 0.$$

We are done.

Comment: So could we conclude that the reason of your method being successful, is that Schur inequality is stronger than AM-GM (at least in three degree)?

Comment: @youthdoo I haven't thought about this question before.

Comment: @youthdoo Check the equality conditions. Apart from $(1, 1, 1)$, we also have $(2, 2, 0)$ (and cyclic permutations). This tells us that AM-GM isn't sufficient, and unlikely to yield a solution unless we do something much more creative.

Comment: @CalvinLin So we want a AM-GM with equality for multiple conditions?

Comment: See [user's solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4616420/54563) for an example of how using AM-GM, we can still get an equality condition of $(0, 0, 1)$ and cyclic permutations.

Comment: @CalvinLin Sometimes in application of Holder inequality, we do similar things.